# Custom csv Import not working in magento 2.3

Tags: import, admin-panel, csv, magento2.3

While doing importing from backend for custom table its trowing  following error

> systemException
>   Additional data:
>   Error in data structure: entity values are mixed

but its correct validated in magento 2.3 and Same code is working with magento 2.2.6

Any suggestion please share

Answer (score 1):

In 2.3.1 I found that this code is compulsory. After 2.2.6 magento requires `sku` compulsory. So this problem is comes. I face this problem and i follow this url. 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19761

I put sku in my custom code. and my code is working fine. My problem is solved.

I wrote like this:

```
class CustomImport extends \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity {  
const SKU = 'sku';  
const ADD1 = 'add1'; 
...... 


protected $validColumnNames = [    
self::DESCRIPTION,  
self::COMPANY,  
self::SKU,  
self::ADD1,  
self::ADD2,  
self::ADD3,  
self::ADD4,  
self::ADD5,  
self::CITY,  
self::STATE,  
self::ZIP,  
self::COUNTRY,    
    ];
}
```